# Any idea about knowing which cache line has been accessed by a process

Tags: caching

I'm looking how to taint cache lines according to processes have accessed. For example, when a process accesses a cache line, that cache line will be tainted for the processes. Any idea about knowing which cache line has been accessed by a process?

Regards,

Comment: Please, just want to know, if that possible or not.